# Git Pages Not Displaying Images

Tags: git, image, deployment

I started coding my first website for a family member's business, and decided I would deploy it in git pages to check and make sure it looks decent. The first image I added displays perfectly, but the rest of the images aren't displaying at all. I've tried using ./images & ../images & /images nothing seems to fix it. help please :)

--Solved---- Git didnt save all my images as .jpg, it saved some as .JPG ---

[My Git](https://github.com/nateHamshar)
[Git Pages index.html](https://natehamshar.github.io/simplyaglazing/simply-v2/#)

Comment: Note that *Git* is case-sensitive, even if your particular OS / file-system isn't. This mismatch (between Git believing that a file named `x.jpg` file and one named `x.JPG` file are entirely different, with your OS saying that these are the *same* file) is the cause of a lot of grief with Git, if you have one of those OS / file-system combinations.

Comment: @nate Consider to add your solution as an answer to this post, and mark that answer as correct. This way, the question is marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--Solved---- Git didnt save all my images as .jpg, it saved some as .JPG ---

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).